# Calling the filter method on a JQuery object is not working when done inside of a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

My knowledge of jQuery and more specifically javascript has always been very limited and I am working hard to get better.

With that in mind I am trying to create some sort of "extensible validation framework" in that I can create an object with a validation function and its error message, push it into an array and then call all those methods and report the messages from the ones that fail.

So first I did something very simple just to see that the basic validation worked which was this:

```
var selectedTourDate = $("#tourDate").val();
var list = $("#bookedTourDate *");

var isDateBooked = list.filter(function () {
    return (this.innerHTML == selectedTourDate) ;
}).length !== 0;

if (isDateBooked) {
    alert("Date invalid");
    return;
}
```

This works fine.

Then I created my "framework" which is this:

```
function Validator(fn, errorMessage) {
    this.validationFunction = fn;
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
};

var validationRunner = {
    validators: [],
    errorMessages: [],
    validationResult: true,

    addValidation: function (validator) {
        validationRunner.validators.push(validator);
    },

    validate: function () {
        for (var validator = 0; validator < validationRunner.validators.length; validator++) {
            if (validationRunner.validators[validator] instanceof Validator) {
                var result = validationRunner.validators[validator].validationFunction();
                validationResult = validationRunner.validationResult && result;

                if (!result)
                    validationRunner.errorMessages.push(validationRunner.validators[validator].errorMessage);
            }
        }
    },

    getErrorMessage: function () {
        var message = "<ul>";

        for (var errorMessage = 0; errorMessage > validationRunner.errorMessages.length; errorMessage++) {
            message += "<li>" + errorMessage + "</li>";
        }

        message += "</ul>";
        return message;
    }
}
```

And then modified the first block of code as follows:

```
var selectedTourDate = $("#tourDate").val();
var list = $("#bookedTourDate *");

var tmp = new Validator(function () {
    return list.filter(function () {
         return (this.innerHTML == selectedTourDate);
    }).length !== 0;
}, "Date already booked");

validationRunner.addValidation(tmp);
validationRunner.validate();
var msg = validationRunner.getErrorMessage();
```

This does not work at all.

It seems that the problem is that in this statement:

> return (this.innerHTML == selectedTourDate);

The "this" is the Validator object instead of the html element from the list which confuses me since as its inside the function of the "filter" method it should be.

Is there a way to correct this so I can accomplish what I am trying to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` does have the correct value but there are some mistakes in the `getErrorMessage function`.

To check the value of `this` don't rely on a debugger's "watch variable" function but do a `console.log` which will give you the value at a specific point of the code execution.

My changes:

```
    for (var errorMessage = 0; errorMessage < validationRunner.errorMessages.length; errorMessage++) {
        message += "<li>" + validationRunner.errorMessages[errorMessage] + "</li>";
    }
```

The `errorMessage` variable is only a index and not the actual error message. Also you used a "bigger than" instead of a "smaller than" sign.

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbBTx/4/)

Comment: I hadn't seen those errors since I haven't gotten to that part yet. Are you saying that without any modifications the validation worked??!! That confuses me even more because it is NOT working for me!!

Comment: It seems I spoke too soon. You are right by using the console.log instead of a watch expression I am able to get a better understanding of what is going on and, hopefully, fix the problem. Thank you.

Comment: All I changed is the `getErrorMessage` function. I did have to guess the HTML, so if it's still not working for you maybe that's the problem. If you update the fiddle I'll take another look.

Comment: Thanks. Everything is good. With the comments on the getErrorMessage function and the recommendation to use console.log was a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

That is very odd, as this should be the current DOM element per [jquery api](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

The function should take an index as a parameter, though. So what about trying

```
return list.filter(function (i) {
  return (list.get(i).innerHTML == selectedTourDate);
}).length !== 0;
```